# Need NSIS example script with all necessary files for script to run

Tags: nsis

I am very new to NSIS, and i was wondering if there is a way to change the splash screen with modern UI, on the first and last pages:

[Installer Closing Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNMYk.png)

[Installer Opening Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpDdu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP "c:\myfiles\wizard.bmp"
!include MUI2.nsh
...
```

This is of course [documented in the Readme](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Modern%20UI%202/Readme.html).